# Python2: installing networkx

Tags: python, pip, networkx

I'm tryng to install networkx on python 2.7.18:

```
pip2 install networkx
```

I get the following error:

```
Running setup.py install for networkx ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-install-xAglEZ/networkx/setup.py'"'"'; _file='"'"'/private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-install-xAglEZ/networkx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-record-cJQmE6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/networkx
         cwd: /private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-install-xAglEZ/networkx/
```

and in the end:

```
error: could not create '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/networkx-2.2': Permission denied
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-install-xAglEZ/networkx/setup.py'"'"'; _file='"'"'/private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-install-xAglEZ/networkx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1b/8lq89lxj07bd6rvtl1k6g1b80000gn/T/pip-record-cJQmE6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/networkx Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have sufficient privileges.

---

You can either run the command with `sudo` (if you are a root user):

```
sudo pip2 install networkx
```

or just install it just for the current user

```
pip2 install networkx --user
```

---

PS: Consider upgrading to `pip3`.

---